# Are All Bayesian Methods also Parameteric?

Tags: bayesian

Bayesian methods have belief over the prior distribution over variables. They update this belief with evidence.

We know that parametric statistical methods are considered to be methods which have an assumption on the distribution of the variables.

My question: Since, Bayesian methods use a prior distribution over the variables, are all bayesian methods also parameteric?

Comment: Google returns many relevant results for "Bayesian nonparametric." Since I'm sure you've looked over those results, perhaps you could explain how what those authors call nonparametric is not consistent with your understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Bayesian nonparametrics involves putting priors not on families of probability distributions indexed by (a) parameter[s], but on a (potentially infinite) space of densities themselves.

A simple example of this might be plain old posterior mode estimation (the Bayesian equivalent of maximum likelihood). A normal density is one which is strongly unimodal. But so is a T-distribution, a double exponential, etc. Suppose further you don't feel comfortable saying anything more about the prior than the fact that it is strongly unimodal (convex density). You can actually sample from the posterior of such a distribution making a bare minimum of assumptions and obtain estimates and credible intervals. It is in my humble opinion super cool because it hybridizes Bayesian and likelihood based inference. [Source](http://econpapers.repec.org/article/eeestapro/v_3a14_3ay_3a1992_3ai_3a3_3ap_3a195-199.htm).

Comment: cool thanks! that clears things up. `Likelihood-based inference` is this the same as frequentist inference?